# Compile gradle task only when executed

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

We've written some custom gradle tasks in Kotlin, and as they've grown, they've moved from build.gradle to buildSrc. These tasks are for processes that run in CI and developers don't really need them on their local machines.

The issue is that any time we modify these scripts, when developers pull latest their next gradle command takes an extra 15+ seconds because it has to compile buildSrc again.

Is there a best practice for how I can get `./gradlew <my-custom-task>` to automatically compile and run a Kotlin task from somewhere in the project, but if I run `./gradlew build` it ignores my task and does not attempt to compile it?

Comment: Have you considered pulling those tasks into a Gradle plugin, published to an internal repo?

Comment: @Egor My issue with that approach is that it can't be tested coherently, e.g., if I open a PR build to main, the version of the tool running in that build is not reflective of the changes in the PR, it has to be merged, published, and then tested with a version bump. That's not an option we want to pursue.

Comment: @ElliotNelson To skip tasks when running other tasks which have them in their graph you can use the [--exclude-task CLI option](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:excluding_tasks_from_the_command_line). Apart from that Egor's advice seems to be the best option and I'd strongly recommend it - it is the "best practice" you are looking for.